# Why does the height of footer run out of the area?

Tags: html, css

[image]

I didn't set height to the footer,so the height is suposed to be from the "Recent posts" to the bottom.

But it seems like there is a problem with the height.

did anyone encounter this kind of problem before? How do you deal with it?

I don't want to set max-height to the footer,because it should be flexible to the widget area.

Maybe it is the problem with leaving out div close tag???unlikely...

```
footer{
font-size: 1.4rem;
}

.container_12 {
width: 1024px;
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
}

.sidebar-widget > *
{

    display: inline-block;
    margin: 50px 30px;
    vertical-align: top;


}
```

basically it's all I wrote.

```
    <!-- footer -->
    <footer class="footer" role="contentinfo">
        <div class="container_12">

            <div class="footer-sidebar">
                <?php get_sidebar(); ?>

            </div>

            <!-- copyright -->
            <p class="copyright">
                &copy; <?php echo date("Y"); ?> Copyright <?php bloginfo('name'); ?>. <?php _e('Powered by', 'html5blank'); ?> 
                <a href="//wordpress.org" title="WordPress">WordPress</a> &amp; <a href="//html5blank.com" title="HTML5 Blank">HTML5 Blank</a>.
            </p>
            <!-- /copyright -->

        </div>
    </footer>
    <!-- /footer -->
```

it's something from wordpress

---

OK,I got it.
I have to clearfix the content-warpper before the footer.

Comment: You need to share your code here, how we can answer without that?

Comment: Please share your solution as a new answer, don't leave it as part of the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think if you add overflow:hidden for your footer class this work correctly. you can check it.

```
.container_12 {
width: 1024px;
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
overflow: hidden;
}
```